# Launch Cordova Windows App with Parameters

Tags: windows, cordova, launch

Am finding hard to launch Cordova Windows App, from another native Windows App.

Using `Protocol invocation`, I am passing few parameters to `Cordova Windows App`, to see if the Cordova app identifies those parameters from the Windows Native App.

Is there anyway to pass Parameters from `native Windows App` to `Cordova App`, so that `Cordova App` identifies the parameters as arguments?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you share with us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

In native windows 8 store app I am using app protocol association to send  parameters one app to another app. like

in sender app:
mainpage.xaml.cs on button click

```
var url = "apptest:?" + name;
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

in received app

```
Package.appxmanifest:
```

Declarations --> available declarations add --> protocol --> name = apptest

**app.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {

            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs protocolArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

            var rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), protocolArgs);

            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

**mainpage.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        ProtocolActivatedEventArgs pa = e.Parameter as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

        if(pa != null)enter code here
        {
            string qS = pa.Uri.Query;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qS))
            {
                Txt_name.Text = qS;
            }
        }          

    }
```

in this way i will take the data from sender app.

Same like is there any way to receive data from windows 10 native app to cordova app. it is very hard to find the solution. not able to find the exact piece of code.